# Assigning a variable as constant and find out the minimum value

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematica

I have got a problem in assigning a variable as constant and solving a equations for minimum value. These are my equations:

kd (2 h2 Cos[[Theta]2] - 
    b2 Sin[[Theta]2]) (b1 - (b1 + b2) Cos[[Theta]1] + 
    b2 Cos[[Theta]2] + 2 h1 Sin[[Theta]1] + 
    2 h2 Sin[[Theta]2]) == (b2 g (m2 + md) + 
     h2 (m2 + 2 md) xg) Cos[[Theta]2] + (g h2 (m2 + 2 md) - 
     b2 (m2 + md) xg) Sin[[Theta]2]

Sin[[Theta]1] (b1^2 kd + b1 b2 kd - g h1 (m1 + 2 (m2 + md)) - 
     b2 (m2 + md) xg - 
     b1 (m1 + m2 + md) xg + (b1 + b2) kd (b2 Cos[[Theta]2] + 
        2 h2 Sin[[Theta]2])) + 
  Cos[[Theta]1] (b2 g (m2 + md) + b1 (2 h1 kd + g (m1 + m2 + md)) - 
     h1 (m1 + 2 (m2 + md)) xg + 
     2 h1 kd (b2 Cos[[Theta]2] + 2 h2 Sin[[Theta]2])) == 
 2 (b1 + b2) h1 kd Cos[2 [Theta]1] + 
  1/2 ((b1 + b2)^2 - 4 h1^2) kd Sin[2 [Theta]1]

[Theta]20 > [Theta]10

[Theta]10 > 0

By using these four equation how can I found minimum value of xg. In this problem there are only three variable rest of all other are constant. The three variables are [Theta]10, [Theta]20 and xg. I tried to use Reduce{} command but I don't know which is suitable for this problem.
Please be kind enough to assist in this regard. Thank you in advance for responding.

Comment: Your question would be much easier to read if you formatted it in MathJax.  For more info, try this link : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference